# How to Clear WMI MDM_AssignedAccess configuration?

Tags: powershell, wmi, mdm, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm using WMI MDM Bridge to configure Multi-App Kiosk mode in Windows 10.

```
$nameSpaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className="MDM_AssignedAccess"
$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$obj.Configuration = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode(@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 ... CONFIGURATOIN HERE ...

Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj
```

WMI Explorer shows me that MDM_AssignedAccess.Instance class has a new property now called COnfiguration.

Is there any way available to cleanup the configuration and revert Windows to the previous state?

What I tried:

- Clear-AssignedAccess - no effect
- Manually clear configuration property - Error with Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj command
- Also I tried to find the way to remove new "configuration" property with no effect.

It looks like a one-way road. I want to be able to revert Multi-App kiosk mode if needed.

I have one more question - Is it possible to provide command line options to the allowed apps in multi-app kiosk?

For me,

```
rs5:AutoLaunchArguments="ARGS_HERE"
```

does not work as well as

```
rs5:AutoLaunch="true"
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If a user is signed-in or the computer has a PS/2 keyboard, you must restart the computer to apply the changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/assignedaccess/clear-assignedaccess?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but Clear-AssignedAccess cmdlet will not work for the Multi-App configuration. It works fine for the single-app kiosk mode only (provided by using Set-AssignedAccess cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

##To remove the existing Multi-App Kiosk configuration settings

$aacsp = Get-CimInstance -Namespace “root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap” -ClassName “MDM_AssignedAccess”

$aacsp.Configuration = $NULL

Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $aacsp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).